# what's the best way to initialize reactive variable without value in vue3 with typescript?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I would like to initialize a `reactive` variable without a value.
I tried:

```
const workspaceReact = reactive(null) // wrong! it is seems value null can not being passed to reactive()
```

So I tried the following code, and it seems to work:

```
let workspaceReact:UnwrapRef<ToolboxInfo>;
workspaceReact = reactive(toolbox)
```

but I feel it's too complicated.
Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to switch from `reactive` to a `ref`, and use the [Reactivity Transform](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#reactivity-transform) in `<script setup>`, which automatically unwraps `ref`s.

To use it, replace `ref`/`computed` with `$ref`/`$computed` (no import needed):

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

type ToolboxInfo = {
  name: string
  id: string
  counter: number
}
                       
let workspaceReact = $ref<ToolboxInfo | null>(null)
let msg = $computed(() => `Hello ${workspaceReact?.name}!`)
const onClick = () => workspaceReact!!.counter++

onMounted(() => {
  workspaceReact = {
    id: 'my id',
    name: 'my toolbox',
    counter: 0,
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-reactivity-transform-2?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyComponent.vue)

**Caveat:** As of `vue@3.2.37`, this feature is still experimental:

> ##### ⚠️ Experimental Feature
>
> Reactivity Transform is currently an experimental feature. It is disabled by default and requires [explicit opt-in](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#explicit-opt-in). It may also change before being finalized. To stay up-to-date, keep an eye on its [proposal and discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/discussions/369).

Comment: @Daniel Updated with note

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible.
A `reactive` needs to extend an object
https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#reactive

> ### reactive()
>
> Returns a reactive proxy of the object.
>
> ##### Type
>
> ```
> function reactive<T extends object>(target: T): UnwrapNestedRefs<T>
> ```

Your options are:

- Initialize with an empty object `{}`
- use a `ref`